# Help with Polar Decomposition Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

In this video, the outline of the proof is given for the polar value decomposition

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12sKshiNalg

We want to write square matrix A as $A = QS$ where $Q$ is an isometry and $S$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.

The video handles the case where $S$ is invertible.
$A^TA = SQ^TQS = S^2$, so $S=\sqrt{A^TA}$, which is indeed positive semi-definite.

To check $Q$ is indeed an isometry, $Q = AS^{-1}$, so $Q^TQ = S^{-1}A^TAS^{-1} = I$.

How do we check that Q is an isometry if $S$ is not invertible?

Comment: Yes that's a plausible thought, i get the unitary from a continuity argument, ( unitary $U$ is a full rank isometry in this notation ) the idea is well used in proofs, you approximate $A$ by $A_{\epsilon}$ to have it invertible then $A_{\epsilon}=U_{\epsilon}P_{\epsilon}$ at the limit $U$ is nessecairily unitary (unitaries are closed set) and $P$ positive SEMI-definite.